# Провести расчёт на остаток Swift

Tags: swift

Функция то работает, но решение не правильно, не могу понять как правильно реализовать.

Функция получает параметр - количество денег, провести расчет и вывести на экран сколько алкоголя сможем заказать, учитывая что в первую очередь мы берем самый дорогой алкоголь, когда не хватает денег - еще дешевле и потом еще дешевле.
Цены на алкоголь в баре:
Виски - 100
Водка - 10
Пиво - 1

Input example:
111

Output example:
whiskey: 1, vodka: 1, beer: 1

Naming rule:

```
func alcoholParty(money: Int) {
    let whiskey = money / 100
    let vodka = whiskey % 10
    let beer =  vodka / 1
    print("whiskey: \(whiskey), vodka: \(vodka), beer: \(beer)")
}
alcoholParty(money: 111)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проверить другие примеры, 211 например, то функция не сработает. Whiskey находится правильно - целое от деления на 100, как первая итерация. Vodka нужно находить на остаток денег после покупки whiskey, т.е. (money % 100) / 10, а beer это остаток после нахождения whiskey и vodka или число денег, за которое нельзя купить whiskey и  vodka. Можно записать это вот так:

```
func alcoholParty(money: Int) {
    let whiskey = money / 100
    let vodka = (money % 100) / 10
    let beer =  money % 10
    print("whiskey: \(whiskey), vodka: \(vodka), beer: \(beer)")
}
alcoholParty(money: 211)
```

whiskey: 2, vodka: 1, beer: 1

Comment: В общем случае (цены не являются последовательными степенями какого-либо числа) нужно уменьшать money на истраченную сумму, иначе для трех предметов третья строка посчитает неправильно.

Comment: Согласен. Третья строка для красоты)